# Ngrx causes hanging issue until page is reloaded when subscribing to store.dispatch

Tags: angular, ngrx, store

i'm quite new to the Ngrx store, but i have an implementation that seems to work.

i've noticed a strange behaviour in my login screen i'm building. i want to handle GetUserFailures in a specific way, so i subscribe to `ScannedActionsSubject` and filter by action type.

```js
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private actions$: ScannedActionsSubject,
) {
    ...
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.actions$
      .pipe(filter((action: any) => action.type === '[User] Get User Failure'))
      .subscribe((action: any) => {
        const error = action.payload.error.response;
        this.handleError(error);
        if (error && error.includes('not found')) {
          this.snackBar.open('Sorry, we have no record of that email address.', 'OK');
        } else if (error && error.includes('Invalid credentials')) {
          this.snackBar.open('The password you entered is incorrect.', 'OK');
        }
        if (this.loading) this.loading = false;
      });
  }

  async login(event: any) {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();

    // if the user is logging in for the first time, show update password form
    if (this.validateForm(this.loginForm)) {
      this.loading = true;
      const email = this.loginForm.controls.email.value;
      email && this.store.dispatch(new GetUserByEmail(email));
      this.store.select(selectUserByEmail)
        .pipe(filter(result => result.user !== (null || undefined)))
        .subscribe(
          async (result) => {
            this.user = result.user;
            if (this.user && this.user.status === 'Pending') {
              const email = this.loginForm.controls.email.value;
              const password = this.loginForm.controls.password.value;
              email && password && this.userService.validatePasswordHash(email, password).subscribe(
                (result) => {
                  if (result) {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.loginStepper.selectedIndex = 2;
                    this.hidePassword = true;
                  }
                }, 
                (error) => {
                  this.handleError(error);
                  if (error.error && error.error.response.includes('Invalid credentials')) {
                    this.snackBar.open('The password you entered is incorrect.', 'OK');
                    this.loading = false;
                    return;
                  }
                },
              );
            } else if (this.user && this.user.status === 'Active') {
              localStorage.setItem('USER_AUTHD', 'true');
              await this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
              this.snackBar.open(`Welcome back, ${this.user.recipientFullName.split(' ')[0]}!`, 'OK', { duration: 4000 });
            } else {
              console.log('neither active nor pending!', this.user);
            }
            this.loading = false;
            return;
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log('Error getting user by email', error);
            return;
          },
          () => {  // complete
            if (this.loading) this.loading = false;
          },
        );
  }
}
```

when an error occurs, the error is handled correctly, but when i try to kick off my login process again, the `store.select` piece hangs indefinitely and i can't seem to figure out why. it's definitely not the best implementation as far as readability but it's all i've come up with for working functionality.

just to reiterate, after the first login attempt fails, each login attempt after "hangs" inside the login flow, specifically the `this.store.select(selectUserByEmail)`, but tracing the cause of the hang is difficult as I can only see as far as the network request for GetUserByEmail, which works.

i'd like to be able to "reload" the system for more login attempts.

GetUserByEmail effect:

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {

  @Effect()
  getUserByEmail$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<GetUserByEmail>(UserActionsEnum.GetUserByEmail),
    switchMap((action) => this.userService.getUserByEmail(action.payload)),
    map((response) => new GetUserSuccess(response)),
    catchError((error) => of(new GetUserFailure(error))),
  );
}
```

reducer:

```
case UserActionsEnum.GetUserByEmail:
  return {
    ...state,
    user: action.payload?.data,
    loading: false,
  };
```

Comment: Could you also show the effect that listens to `GetUserByEmail` and the reducer that updates the piece of state which `selectUserByEmail` is based on?

Comment: @AndreiGătej yes, see edits please

Comment: What happens if you use the catchError as ‘getUserByEmal.pipe(catchError()..)...’?

Comment: @AndreiGătej doesn't seem to make a difference, still hangs.

Comment: I think the initial problem was that due to an error, the effect would be unsubscribed. So it thought moving the catchError in the switchMap’s inner observable will prevent that

Comment: @AndreiGătej sorry, i misunderstood what you meant initially, but that fixed it! thank you so much. add an answer if you like, otherwise i'll add one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial problem was that due to an error, the effect would be unsubscribed. So what you could do is to move the `catchError` in the `switchMap`’s inner observable:

```js
...

switchMap(
 (action) => this.userService.getUserByEmail(action.payload).pipe(catchError(...))
),

...
```